# Atollic TrueStudio (Eclipse) Debug Expressions array cut to parts

Tags: arrays, eclipse, debugging, expression, truestudio

I would like to copy all of the elements of an array to excel sheet by debuging variables in Expression panel in the Atollic TrueStudio for STM32 9.1.0. During debug in the expression panel I can easily select the array elements and the ctrl+c -> ctrl+v just works well.

But if the array has many elements, like 8192 elements in my case, then the expression panel cuts this array into length of 100 element parts. See pic below.

[Expression panel screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRhfS.png)
[image]

It is really to pain to collect all of the data from this big array.

Is there any settings for this?

Or any orher workaround?